# Windows 8 Speech Recognition Language

Tags: windows-8, speech-recognition

I've got Windows 8 Pro installed (RTM version from MSDN). For an application I use I need to have the speech recognition language set to English - US. The only option I have is English - UK. I have tried going to Language in Control Panel and setting the only language to English - US, however English - UK is still the only option in speech properties.

How can I add a language to the Speech Properties?[image]

Comment: Should have added the version I installed was English UK Windows 8 x64 (iso name: en-gb_windows_8_x64_dvd_915412.iso). Does that prevent me from getting English - US?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

1) Download the x64 Language Pack DVD ISO

2) Navigate to the EN-US folder and copy the lp.cab file to a local hard drive

3) Rename the .cab file to .mlc and double click it

4) Run through the wizard to install the language

5) Open Advanced Speech Options and EN-US is now available

Answer (score 7):

This probably has not changed from Windows 7, where the speech recognition language is tied to the language specified for the OS. Try getting and installing the English-US language pack and it should become available as an option for speech rec. Here is a [blog that discusses installing language packs in Windows 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312085110/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/07/win8-howto-11-install-language-packs-for-multilingual-support.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. As I mentioned in the question, I have tried just installing the English-US Language Pack, and uninstalling the Australian Language Pack. After a restart, my only option is still English - UK

Comment: I realised that I had installed the EN-US language, but not the language pack. After installing the language pack it did fix the problem.