# Installing Speech recognition language in windows 10 build 10074

Tags: windows-10-preview, language-pack, speech-recognition

I followed this thread to try to install an en-US speech recognition pack on windows 10 build 10074: [Windows 8 Speech Recognition Language](https://superuser.com/questions/475926/windows-8-speech-recognition-language)

Under windows 10 this does not seem to work however. The display language is available but my only speech recognition option remains en-UK.

Is there any way I can manually add the language (move over files) or is there a workaround/fix for this problem?

Comment: It most likely is due to it being beta software yes, but that doesn't mean there isn't a workaround. en-UK came with the computer. en-Us installed.

Comment: got the 10074 language pack from MSDN